# How to deal with HKT types in a pattern matching when you use 'type' keyword to create them?

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

I have this code and of course during a compilation I have this error

> ... is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
>              case map: MapWithObject => value(map, path, index + 1)

How to change a pattern matching case to get rid off that message?

```
type MapWithObject = java.util.HashMap[String, Object]

def value[T : ClassTag](parsedMap: MapWithObject,
                        path: String,
                        index: Int = 0): Option[T] = {
    val key = if (path.contains(".")) path.split("\\.")(index) else path
    parsedMap.asScala.get(key).flatMap({
        case value: T => Some(value)
        case map: MapWithObject => value(map, path, index + 1)
        case _ => None
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of `unchecked`-warnings, use `@unchecked` (since you already have essentially untyped `Object`s flying everywhere, an `@unchecked` annotation 
doesn't make it worse):

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import java.util.{HashMap => JHashMap}

type MapWithObject = JHashMap[String, Object]

def value[T: ClassTag](
  parsedMap: MapWithObject,
  path: String,
  index: Int = 0
): Option[T] = {
  val key = if (path.contains(".")) path.split("\\.")(index) else path
  parsedMap.asScala.get(key).flatMap({
    case value: T => Some(value)
    case map: JHashMap[String @unchecked, Object @unchecked] =>
      value(map, path, index + 1)
    case _ => None
  })
}
```

As a remedy for the lengthy `java.util.HashMap`, you can use a renaming import `HashMap => JHashMap` instead of a type definition.